# Using modulo function to implement power with multiply

Tags: c++

This is my `powmod` function:

```
int powmod(int b, int e, int m)
{
    int result = 1;
    while(e > 0){
        if(e & 1){
            result *= b;
            result %= m;
        }
        b *= b;
        b %= m;
        e >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

So when I use this function I just simply insert:

```
powmod(2,6,11);
```

which is 2^6 mod 11, if I want to insert (2^6*11) mod p.
How should I modify or insert the value?

It is not same as:

```
powmod(2,6,11) * (11%p); //the result is different from (2^6*11) mod p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean `(2^(6*11)) mod p`, you should insert the result of calling `powmod(2, 6 * 11, p)`

If you mean `((2^6) * 11) mod p`, you can do the following

```
long long int a = powmod(2, 6, p);
a *= 11 % p;  /* mod -> % */
a %= p;
```

`(int)a` contains your required value, so insert it.

As a side note, ints in your function may overflow.

You should capture multiplication results in wider int or write a custom multiplication function that does not overflow.

**IDEA1**

```
int powmod(int b_, int e, int m)
{
    long long int result = 1LL;
    long long int b = b_;
    while(e > 0){
        if(e & 1){
            result *= b;
            result %= m;
        }
        b *= b;
        b %= m;
        e >>= 1;
    }
    return (int)result;
}
```

**IDEA2**

```
int safe_mul(int m1, int m2, int modulus) {
  /* Useful for competetions where modulus is usually 10^9 + 7 or 10^9 + 9 */
  /* If modulus is larger, this would need more modifications while adding */
  int i = 0, j = m1;
  while(m2) {
    if(m2 % 2) i = (i + j) % modulus;
    j = (2 * j) % modulus;
    m2 /= 2;
  }
  return i % modulus;
}

int powmod(int b, int e, int m)
{
    int result = 1;
    while(e > 0){
        if(e & 1){
            result = safe_mul(result, b, p);
            result %= m;
        }
        b = safe_mul(b, b, p);
        e >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Both ideas are just to give an idea how you can achieve the functionality. Actual implementation may depend on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Mohit Jain answered this correctly by reducing the generalised call, which would have been:

```
int val = powmod( powmod(2,6,11)*11, 1, 11 );
```

But I would just like to point out that `x * y (mod y)`, is always zero.  So in fact, your example reduces to:

```
int val = 0;
```